# Groovy script to modify text file line by line

Tags: file, groovy, soapui

I have a input file from which a Groovy file reads input. Once a particular input is processed, Groovy script should be able to comment the input line it used and then move on.

File content:

```
1   
2        
3
```

When it processes line 1 and line 2, the input file will look as below:

```
'1    
'2                   
3
```

By this way, if I re-run the Groovy, I would like to start from the line it stopped last time. If a input was used and it failed, that particular line shall not be commented (`'`) so that a retry can be attempted.

Appreciate if you can help to draft a Groovy script.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try something, show us what you have, and we can help. Perhaps have a read through [ask].

Comment: @sshark share your code so you'll have more chances to get answer

Comment: You could do some of this with Java random access file stuff--BUT with random access you can only append or alter, not insert.  So if you were comfortable changing your "1" to " 1" beforehand you could do it, or you could change "1" to a comment character but you lose your number. to insert would require re-writing everything past the insert--might as well re-write the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK in *Groovy* you can only append text at the end of the file.

Hence to add `'` on each line when it is processed you need to rewrite the entire file.

You can use the follow approach but I only recommend you to use for a small files since you're loading all the lines in memory. In summary an approach for your question could be:

```
// open the file
def file = new File('/path/to/sample.txt')
// get all lines
def lines = file.readLines()

try{
    // for each line
    lines.eachWithIndex { line,index ->
        // if line not starts with your comment "'"
        if(!line.startsWith("'")){
            // call your process and make your logic...
            // but if it fails you've to throw an exception since
            // you can not use 'break' within a closure
            if(!yourProcess(line)) throw new Exception()

            // line is processed so add the "'"
            // to the current line
            lines.set(index,"'${line}")
        }
     }
}catch(Exception e){
  // you've to catch the exception in order
  // to save the progress in the file
}

// join the lines and rewrite the file
file.text = lines.join(System.properties.'line.separator')

// define your process...
def yourProcess(line){
    // I make a simple condition only to test...
    return line.size() != 3
}
```

An optimal approach to avoid load all lines in memory for a large files is to use a reader to read the file contents, and a temporary file with a writer to write the result, and optimized version could be:

```
// open the file
def file = new File('/path/to/sample.txt')

// create the "processed" file
def resultFile = new File('/path/to/sampleProcessed.txt')

try{
    // use a writer to write a result
    resultFile.withWriter { writer ->
        // read the file using a reader 
        file.withReader{ reader ->
            while (line = reader.readLine()) {

                // if line not starts with your comment "'"
                if(!line.startsWith("'")){

                    // call your process and make your logic...
                    // but if it fails you've to throw an exception since
                    // you can not use 'break' within a closure
                    if(!yourProcess(line)) throw new Exception()

                    // line is processed so add the "'"
                    // to the current line, and writeit in the result file
                    writer << "'${line}" << System.properties.'line.separator'
                }    
            }
        }
    }

}catch(Exception e){
  // you've to catch the exception in order
  // to save the progress in the file
}

// define your process...
def yourProcess(line){
    // I make a simple condition only to test...
    return line.size() != 3
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks heaps for the script. That is exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately I need to work on larger input file (5000 lines). Not sure if it would be a problem as you suggested.                                                        I am thinking of writing the processed lines into a new file (append). Obviously it requires manual work to again feed to error'ed output file as input again

Comment: @sshark 5000 lines with commands (I suppose that your files is on average less than 100kb but could be also more) it's totally ok in this context, IMO there is no problem to use this approach.

Comment: Thanks guys, much appreciated on timely assistance