# Groovy scripting : append the string to every end of the line

Tags: git, groovy

Using the groovy script to retrieve the SHA, branch from the git repo, below is the scipt

```
def trigger_ref_tracks = "git ls-remote "+remoteUrl+"/"+gitrepoList_tr.trim()+" --branch "+branch+" --heads";
        //print ("\r\n"+trigger_ref_tracks);
        def cmd2 =  trigger_ref_tracks.execute()
        cmd2.waitFor()
        def logFile = new File("/tmp/"+gitrepoList_tr.trim()+"_"+withno_track+".txt")
        String Final_logFile = "/tmp/retired_track_"+withno_track+".txt"
        println("\r\n"+gitrepoList_tr+"===="+branch)
        println "return code: ${cmd2.exitValue()}"
        println "stderr: ${cmd2.err.text}"
        //println "stdout: ${cmd2.in.text}  "
        logFile.append "${cmd2.in.text}"
```

And the result will be :

```
b8e9363a2bcfc03e3bbe6fa4045570967a227cbb    refs/heads/meta/cibuild/acme
457f2d592547925c4f7d790ce4d44588140e938f    refs/heads/meta/releasebuild/acme
9376be234bb0ac2716861ff235009f78fa3efdf6    refs/heads/acme
121b707a4a74d29ae208ecbfd009fab396eaaffa    refs/meta/releasebuild/acme
```

However, please help to modify the groovy script to append the git repo name to every end of the line, for example

```
b8e9363a2bcfc03e3bbe6fa4045570967a227cbb    refs/heads/meta/cibuild/acme  repo1
457f2d592547925c4f7d790ce4d44588140e938f    refs/heads/meta/releasebuild/acme repo1
9376be234bb0ac2716861ff235009f78fa3efdf6    refs/heads/acme repo1
121b707a4a74d29ae208ecbfd009fab396eaaffa    refs/meta/releasebuild/acme repo1
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: @cfrick: already added the code, the result was no error, am looking for hint/suggestion on how to append string to every end of the lines.

Comment: Never mind this link helped - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470723/groovy-script-to-modify-text-file-line-by-line